# solve ratio word problem without algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, fractions, ratio

Four gallons of yellow paint plus two gallons of red paint make orange paint.  I assume this makes six gallons.  So the ratio is 4:2, or 2:1.

Question:  how many gallons of yellow paint, and how many gallons or red paint, to make two gallons of orange paint?

```
2y + r = 2
2y + y = 2
3y = 2
y = 2/3
```

or

```
4y + 2r = 6
(4y + 2r)/3 = 2
```

so I get 4/3 and 2/3.

However, in this section of [the text book](http://www.pearsonschool.com/index.cfm?locator=PS2cJa&PMDBSUBCATEGORYID=25741&PMDBSITEID=2781&PMDBSUBSOLUTIONID=&PMDBSOLUTIONID=6724&PMDBSUBJECTAREAID=&PMDBCATEGORYID=806&PMDbProgramID=32310&elementType=attribute&elementID=1), I'm not sure that it's "allowed" to do any of that.  Is it possible to solve this just with cross-multiplying a ratio?

Their examples setup a ratio with an unknown `n`, cross multiply and solve for `n`.  I don't see how to solve this word problem with that technique.

Comment: Let us "guess" that it is $4$ of yellow and $2$ of red. Oops, wrong guess, we got $6$ gallons. **Scale** by the factor $\frac{2}{6}$.

Comment: huh?  no, the 4:2 is given in the question.  I **assume** that 4 gallons of yellow plus two gallons red equals six gallons.  Not all chemicals work that way, sometimes 2 gallons of x plus 4 gallons of y only give 5 gallons.  I don't know what you're saying about a guess of 6....?  It's not a guess, it's an assumption not stated in the question.  Yes, scale by 1/3....but how?  There's no algebra in this section.

Comment: Yes, the $4:2$ is given in the question, and yes, alcohol and water don't behave this way, but we have been asked to assume paint does. What I am saying is that since you know that $4$ and $2$ give $6$, to get $2$ we must scale by $\frac{2}{6}$, giving $4\cdot\frac{2}{6}$, $2\cdot\frac{2}{6}$.

Comment: ok, I see what you're saying. interesting.

Comment: Claude Leibovici has given a clearer exposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Take the problem in the other way.

You are told that $6$ gallons of orange paint are made mixing $4$ gallons of yellow paint and $2$ gallons of red paint.

Divide these numbers by 6 in order to come back to one gallon of orange paint. Then, one gallon of orange paint is made mixing $\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$ gallons of yellow paint and $\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$ gallons of red paint.

Now, multiply by $n$ which is the number of gallons of orange paint you want to make.

So, making $n$ gallons of orange paint require mixing $\frac{2n}{3}$ gallons of yellow paint and $\frac{n}{3}$ gallons of red paint.

Now, you want $n=2$; then ....

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: ok, this is interesting, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Thinking simple helps quite often. If you like my answer, you can accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio is $2:1$ and so their values are $2x,x$ and their sum is $3x$. to get 2 gallons we put $3x=2\implies x=2/3$. thus the required values are $2/3,4/3$.

Comment: exactly, but that seems to use algebra, or the beginnings of algebra.  In this section they don't seem to have substitution.