# Algebra word problem but done without system of equations

Tags: fractions, ratio

I have this word problem, its well known mixture type of problem, I can solve this using a system of equations, so that is not the issue.
But is it possible to solve this just using numerical ways, such as 
ratio-proportion method.

Here is the problem:

> An 18% brine solution is a salt water mixture which has 18% salt. Bobby mixed some 18% brine solution with some 35% brine solution to make 85 L of 19% brine solution. What is the volume in liters of the 35% brine solution.

I have found another similar like problem here on stackoverflow:
[solve ratio word problem without algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670570/solve-ratio-word-problem-without-algebra)

SO just to give an idea of the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$85\; L$ of a $19\%$ brine solution has $0.19 \times 85 = 16.15\; L$ of salt.
If Bobby just used the $18\%$ solution he would have $0.18 \times 85 = 15.30\; L$ of salt.
So he needed an additional $16.15 - 15.30 = 0.85\; L$ of salt.  If you replace $1\; L$ of $18\%$ solution with $1\; L$ of $35\%$ solution you get an additional $0.35 - 0.18 = 0.17\; L$ of salt.  So we have to do that $0.85/0.17 = 5$ times.  Thus Bobby must have used $80\; L$ of $18\%$ and $5\; L$ of $35\%$ solution.

Comment: Hi, that is a very good numerical approach.

Comment: Hi, i see you used the maximum volume using 18% to get the 15.30L, you got the difference, to see what remains. Then you did a difference of the amount of salt for 1L of each of them to see how one has more than the other. So we can see how much more you get with 0.35, but then getting the 0.85/0.17 to get the "5 times", and then using that somehow, is not too clear to me.

Comment: You need $0.85$ more.  Each one-litre change gives you $0.17$ more.  So you need $0.85/0.17 = 5$ one-litre changes to do that.  A "one-litre change" means one less litre of $18\%$ solution and one more litre of $35\%$ solution.  So five one-litre changes means $85 - 5 = 80$ litres of $18\%$ solution and
$5$ litres of $35\%$ solution.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for this additional detail. Really appreciate it. So I see you are now trying to "Change out" 1 L of one type for another type. That helps me to understand this better. I will award your solutions as the answer to this question.